# When exporting orgmode doc to freemind how to specify unlimited number of levels?

Tags: org-mode

I use `M-x` then `org-freemind-export-to-freemind` in order to export an org-mode doc to freemind.  However, when I open it I see that it's exporting **up to 3 levels** and levels 4 and on becoming notes.  Is it possible to specify to **export all levels as nodes**? (except for actual unleveled standard text notes).

Comment: Not sure you can do unlimited, but try `#OPTIONS: H:1000` or maybe something smaller but still bigger than you document depth.

Comment: excellent! exactly what I needed!

Comment: @NickD Hello, what does that mean to "try `#OPTIONS: H:1000`" Should it be written somewhere in the file ? In configuration ?

Comment: It goes at the top of the file (see [Export settings](https://orgmode.org/manual/Export-Settings.html#Export-Settings)) but it is misspelled: it should be `#+OPTIONS: H:1000`. You can also configure it by setting the variable `org-export-headline-levels` but it is probably more convenient to use the `#+OPTIONS: ` mechanism in the file.